# How can I log all IPs and hostnames a linux system is trying to connect to?

Tags: linux, networking

Hello I would like to log all IPs and host names a linux system is trying to connect to on the linux system directly. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use standard traffic monitoring tools, like `flowcapture` + `ipt_NETFLOW`, (or `softflowd`) to record all IPs, ports, etc. a machine accesses. Then flow-tools utilities will allow you to extract various statistics.

For DNS names it is impossible in case modern inventions like DoH are used. If it's not used, you can set up a DNS resolver and log all queries.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to use `iptables` with `-j LOG`.

Answer (score 0):

you have network monitoring tools for that, like nagios in large scale.

Try these links also

https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.1/admin/policies/enforcing-policy-with-pre-receive-hooks/managing-pre-receive-hooks-on-the-github-enterprise-server-appliance
https://www.tecmint.com/linux-network-bandwidth-monitoring-tools/